# Is there a way to test if anyone pushed to the remote repo using JGit from local repo?

Tags: java, jgit, buildbot

I am designing a User interface in Java and I am trying to make my own buildbot like thing. So for that I want to create a function like buildbot's gitpoller in JGit. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can use a FetchCommand and then inspect the FetchResult. Something like this:

```
Repository repository = FileRepositoryBuilder.create(gitDir);
Git git = Git.wrap(repository);
FetchResult result = git.fetch().call();
for (TrackingRefUpdate refUpdate : result.getTrackingRefUpdates()) {
    // ...
}
```